# Output The Value to the User

Tags: javascript, html

I was trying to figure out how to output the value of num1 num2 and func to the screen for the user to see. This is a calculator app im trying to get fully functional. The app works already but i cannot seem to get the numbers and the operation which is set as variable func to show to the screen to the user.
If you need anymore information please let me know.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  var num1 = []

  var num2 = []

  var func = null

  $('#one').click(function() {
    if (func === null) {
      num1.push('1')
      console.log(num1)
    } else {
      num2.push('1')
      console.log(num2)
    }
  });

  $('#two').click(function() {
    if (func === null) {
      num1.push('2')
      console.log(num1)
    } else {
      num2.push('2')
      console.log(num2)
    }
  });

  $('#three').click(function() {
    if (func === null) {
      num1.push('3')
    } else {
      num2.push('3')
    }
  });

  $('#four').click(function() {
    if (func === null) {
      num1.push('4')
    } else {
      num2.push('4')
    }
  });

  $('#five').click(function() {
    if (func === null) {
      num1.push('5')
    } else {
      num2.push('5')
    }
  });

  $('#six').click(function() {
    if (func === null) {
      num1.push('6')
    } else {
      num2.push('6')
    }
  });

  $('#seven').click(function() {
    if (func === null) {
      num1.push('7')
    } else {
      num2.push('7')
    }
  });

  $('#eight').click(function() {
    if (func === null) {
      num1.push('8')
    } else {
      num2.push('8')
    }
  });

  $('#nine').click(function() {
    if (func === null) {
      num1.push('9')
    } else {
      num2.push('9')
    }
  });

  $("#zero").click(function() {
    if (func === null) {
      num1.push('0')
    } else {
      num2.push('0')
    }
  });

  $('#plus').click(function() {
    func = "+"
    console.log(func)
  });

  $('#minus').click(function() {
    func = "-"
  });

  $('#divide').click(function() {
    func = "/"
  });

  $('#multiply').click(function() {
    func = "*"
    console.log(func)
  });

  $('#equals').click(function() {
    if (func === "+") {
      num1 = num1.join("")
      number1 = parseInt(num1)
      num2 = num2.join("")
      number2 = parseInt(num2)
      var complete = number1 + number2
      console.log(complete)
    } else if (func === "-") {
      num1 = num1.join("")
      number1 = parseInt(num1)
      num2 = num2.join("")
      number2 = parseInt(num2)
      var complete = number1 - number2
      console.log(complete)
    } else if (func === "*") {
      num1 = num1.join("")
      number1 = parseInt(num1)
      num2 = num2.join("")
      number2 = parseInt(num2)
      var complete = number1 * number2
      console.log(complete)
    } else if (func === "/") {
      num1 = num1.join("")
      number1 = parseInt(num1)
      num2 = num2.join("")
      number2 = parseInt(num2)
      var complete = number1 / number2
      console.log(complete)
    } else {
      console.log("error")
    }
  });

  $('#clear').click(function() {
    num1 = []
    num2 = []
    func = null
    console.log(num1)
    console.log(num2)
    console.log(func)
  });



});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.js">
</script>

<div id="calculator-container">
  <form class="show">
    <input type="text" name="numbers" disabled><br>
  </form>
  <center>
    <div class="calculator-view">
      <table>
        <tr>
          <td>
            <button id="clear" type="button">AC</button>
            <button id="sign" type="button">+/-</button>
            <button id="divide" type="button">÷</button>
          </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>
            <button id="seven" type="button">7</button>
            <button id="eight" type="button">8</button>
            <button id="nine" type="button">9</button>
            <button id="multiply" type="button">X</button>
          </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>
            <button id="four" type="button">4</button>
            <button id="five" type="button">5</button>
            <button id="six" type="button">6</button>
            <button id="minus" type="button">-</button>
          </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>
            <button id="one" type="button">1</button>
            <button id="two" type="button">2</button>
            <button id="three" type="button">3</button>
            <button id="plus" type="button">+</button>
          </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>
            <button id="zero" type="button">0</button>
            <button id="equals" type="button">=</button>
          </td>
        </tr>
      </table>
    </div>
```

Comment: Please add your HTML also and what's the error you are getting?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simply display using `$("#res").val(num1);` and instead of `id` I'll suggest `class` and bind all the clicks using class like this

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  var num1 = []

  var num2 = []

  var func = null

  $('.num').click(function() {
    if (func === null) {
      num1.push($(this).text())
      console.log(num1)
      $("#res").val(num1.join(''));

    } else {
      num2.push($(this).text())
      console.log(num2)
      $("#res").val(num2.join(''));
    }
  });

  $('.action').click(function() {
    func = $(this).text();
    console.log(func)
    $("#res").val(func);
  });



  $('#equals').click(function() {
    if (func === "+") {
      num1 = num1.join("")
      number1 = parseInt(num1)
      num2 = num2.join("")
      number2 = parseInt(num2)
      var complete = number1 + number2
      console.log(complete)
    } else if (func === "-") {
      num1 = num1.join("")
      number1 = parseInt(num1)
      num2 = num2.join("")
      number2 = parseInt(num2)
      var complete = number1 - number2
      console.log(complete)
    } else if (func === "*") {
      num1 = num1.join("")
      number1 = parseInt(num1)
      num2 = num2.join("")
      number2 = parseInt(num2)
      var complete = number1 * number2
      console.log(complete)
    } else if (func === "/") {
      num1 = num1.join("")
      number1 = parseInt(num1)
      num2 = num2.join("")
      number2 = parseInt(num2)
      var complete = number1 / number2
      console.log(complete)
    } else {
      console.log("error")
    }
    $("#res").val(complete);
  });

  $('#clear').click(function() {
    num1 = []
    num2 = []
    func = null
    console.log(num1)
    console.log(num2)
    console.log(func)
  });



});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.js">
</script>

<div id="calculator-container">
  <form class="show">
    <input type="text" id="res" name="numbers" disabled><br>
  </form>
  <center>
    <div class="calculator-view">
      <table>
        <tr>
          <td>
            <button id="clear" type="button">AC</button>
            <button id="sign" class="action" type="button">+/-</button>
            <button id="divide" class="action" type="button">÷</button>
          </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>
            <button id="seven" class="num" type="button">7</button>
            <button id="eight" class="num" type="button">8</button>
            <button id="nine" class="num" type="button">9</button>
            <button id="multiply" class="action" type="button">X</button>
          </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>
            <button id="four" class="num" type="button">4</button>
            <button id="five" class="num" type="button">5</button>
            <button id="six" class="num" class="num" type="button">6</button>
            <button id="minus" class="action" type="button">-</button>
          </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>
            <button id="one" class="num" type="button">1</button>
            <button id="two" class="num" type="button">2</button>
            <button id="three" class="num" type="button">3</button>
            <button id="plus" class="action" type="button">+</button>
          </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>
            <button id="zero" class="num"  type="button">0</button>
            <button id="equals" type="button">=</button>
          </td>
        </tr>
      </table>
    </div>
```

Comment: Thank You very much! I really like the binding of all the clicks! really makes the code DRY!

Comment: @Thallius Glad I helped. Please accept the answer :)

Comment: Just a heads up if anyone is looking at this for help later the zero is missing a class on it.

Answer (score 0):

You can simply add a `span` to your page `<span id="result"></span>`

Then, you can show your result with `$('#result').html(complete);`

Also, in the same way you can show numbers while user digits them.

Comment: @Thallius Check my answer